# is there a way to make a full uv sphere from half of uv sphere?

Tags: mesh, rigging

I was making an eyeball, at first i thought i didn't need the entire sphere, so i cut it in half. Now after finished weight painting and everything, the character is a humanoid, and it has quite a large eyes, i realized i needed the entire sphere, or atleast another quarter of it so that it'll not look weird.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In edit mode:

Select the half of the sphere then <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> then <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>90</kbd>

To merge vertices select both halves and press <kbd>m</kbd> > *By Distance*

Comment: you probably mean R, Z, 90, otherwise you will rotate depending on your view orientation

Comment: Sure, you're right I'll edit.